# How to fix this compounding interest program code in java?

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm still a beginner at all of this, and I'm trying to fix this problem that keeps occurring. Essentially, the goal is to find how long it takes for a initial investment to double using loops and not an equation. The program works when the it annually compounds, it doesn't work when it compounds daily or monthly. It answers with a ridiculously large time period like 200 years, and I do not know what I'm doing wrong, and I would really appreciate feedback. Thank you again!

This is my code below:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    class Main 

 {
    public static void main(String[] args)

     {

       int year = 0;
       Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter account balance: $");
       double balance = kbReader.nextDouble();
       System.out.print("Enter interest rate as a decimal: ");
       double interestRate = kbReader.nextDouble(); 


       System.out.print("Enter period: ");
       int period = kbReader.nextInt();

       double targetBalance = 2 * balance;
       while(balance < targetBalance)

      {

         double interest = balance * (interestRate/period);
         balance = balance + interest; 
         year++;

      }

         System.out.println("The time it takes to double : " + year + " years");
         System.out.printf("The final balance: $%.2f",balance);
           }
  }
```

Comment: Your code contains the line `System.out.println("The time it takes to double : " + year + " years");`. How could it ever report the time in a unit other than years, when the string `" years"` is hard-coded into the output?

Comment: what values are you using?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I know I should have commented this, but for period, I am using 1, 12, and 365 as annual, monthly, and daily.

Comment: So, the time is takes should be represented in *periods*, If I entered $100, 5, and 365, it says it takes something like 51, this would be 51 days.  If I entered $100, 5, and 12, it says it takes something like 2, this would be 2 months. - seems correct.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, thanks for all the input. I realized an easy solution was to divide the year by the period at the end. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @kaya3, thank you for telling me about how I basically forced everything into years. I ended up dividing the years by the period at the end so it will convert everything. Thank you so much.